# SSD seems full, but file system says otherwise

Tags: linux, storage, ssd

I'm running CentOS and have a 100GB Micron RealSSD P300. It appears that the drive is almost full, as noted by running `df`:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       94753636 86002428   3937948  96% /
tmpfs           12298364        0  12298364   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1         253871    58571    182193  25% /boot
```

However, running `du /` tells another story:

```
6.9M    /bin
56M     /boot
188K    /dev
28M     /etc
3.3M    /home
251M    /lib
25M     /lib64
16K     /lost+found
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
8.0K    /opt
0       /proc
11M     /root
18M     /sbin
4.0K    /selinux
0       /service
4.0K    /srv
0       /sys
436K    /tmp
1.4G    /usr
1.9G    /var
```

What could be taking up all of these blocks that I can't see? Could the drive just be broken? I don't have too much experience working with SSDs, so perhaps there's an obvious step I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks, this sheds some more light on the matter but does not address my specific issue. I still don't know why there are suddenly so few free blocks.

Comment: You are running `du` as root, right? Else it may be time for a `fsck`